# Is it possible to add extra zero at front of an input if the integer value received is three digit

Tags: jquery

Hi I have an input field that is transmitting integer...

However when I do

```
parseInt($('#postCode').val());
```

I am losing the first digit if the value received is like 0880 . I want to transmit all the four digits but as an integer.. is that possible?Basically I want to make sure that if

```
parseInt($('#postCode').val());
```

is of three digits that just add one extra 0 at the front.

Comment: Why can't it be a string? You can have it as string and add the leading 0 when you need to use it

Answer (score 1):

If you want the leading zero, then it has to be a string. Just don't call `parseInt` at all. With most post codes I've seen, they are a series of digits (or letters and digits), but they aren't *numbers*.

If you want to use `parseInt` to make sure it's a number, you can add back the leading zero; but again, that will be a *string*, not a number.

E.g.:

```
var str = String(parseInt($("#postCode").val(), 10));
while (str.length < 4) {
    str = "0" + str;
}
```

(Note the second argument to `parseInt`; if you're using `parseInt`, you almost always want to tell it what radix — number base — to use.)

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful - in some older browsers (pre ECMAScript 5), a number starting with a 0 is interpreted as an octal number by `parseInt`, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Why do you want to store it as an integer? I would argue that a postcode/zip-code does not semantically represent a number, and so a string is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the answer. Before you do `parseInt`, you can add a check whether it's a number or not. Use `[$.isNumeric()][1]` to check for a numeric type and then if it returns 3 digits, simply add 0 to your `$("#postCode").val()`